# Awesome not re-sizing to fill screen in VMWare instance, though unity does

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, awesome-wm

When I full-screen my ubuntu instance in VMWare, it stays at the same physical size on the screen as it was before full-screen, though when I log-in to the default WM, Ubuntu seems to notice the increased resolution and expand itself so that it fills the whole screen.

Unfortunately, I am now using Awesome WM and when I login to awesome it does not seem to do this.

I suspect this would have something to do with the VMWare tools that I remember installing a while ago on my regular WM, but I'm not sure why they're not working on Awesome.

I can fix this by logging out of awesome, logging into the regular WM, and then logging out and back into awesome but this is tedious and a bit hacky, so I was hoping someone could help me diagnose and correct the issue at hand.

I have experimented a bit and found that I can use xrandr to set it higher and it'll work correctly, but I'd like if it automatically worked this out as it does in the default WM.

Edit: Ideally, it'd be great if it would automatically do this on the login screen before logging into either WM but I understand if this isn't a possibility or if it'd be more work to get working and it isn't that much of a bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on a Fedora VM. I checked what the startup script did in the default Gnome WM, and there was a VMWare script that ran `vmware-user-suid-wrapper` on startup. Running this under Awesome fixed screen resizing.

I added the following to `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` to get it to run automatically when I log in:

```
-- {{{ Programs to run on login                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-- Need to run this upon login for VMWare                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
os.execute("vmware-user-suid-wrapper &")
-- }}}
```

Comment: Can't test right now but I'm fairly convinced this would fix the issue - Thanks for sharing!